# Question word in "Wie/was ist deine Adresse/Nummer?"

Tags: usage, question

> (a) Wie ist deine Adresse/Nummer?
>
> (b) Was ist deine Adresse/Nummer?

I usually see version (a), rather than (b). Why is it that "wie" is used, even though the question corresponds to "what" rather than "how"? Is version (b) correct?

Comment: "Was" in german has not always the same semantic value of "which". The answer to "was ist deine Adresse?" can thus only be: "Meine Adresse ist eine Adresse" (or some longer definition of "Adresse").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of what-questions in English correspond to wie-questions in German.

What is your name? - Wie ist Ihr Name?

What is her hair like? - Wie ist ihre Haarfarbe?

et cetera.

Version b is not correct. It is English translated word for word into German.

Comment: Version b) is used a lot though.

Comment: Habe ich noch nicht bemerkt.Vielleicht regional. Oder Einfluß des Englischen? Was sagt der Sprachatlas?

Comment: Version b) klingt für mich komisch. Ich glaube @rogermue hat recht.